# Jquery scrolling back to top of page instead of required div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/Stratos123/qywaLszg/ the code for what i am trying to do. The isotope works perfectly and when you click the image the box opens up with the correct information but what happens is once the box is clicked the page scrolls to the top of the html page instead of scrolling to where the navigation is under the red box in example.

If i change the following code

```
  // Portfolio Open and close   
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.portfolio li a').click(function() {
      var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.portfolio').addClass('item_open');

to:

  // Portfolio Open and close   
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery li a').click(function() {
      var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.gallery').addClass('item_open');
```

the portfolio opens and closes perfectly but then the isotop wont work.

Any ideas? I have been working on this for almost 2 weeks now. Going insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qywaLszg/6/embedded/result/

---

**Update**

To work with your ul list you need to adjust the classes when you call the filter

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/qywaLszg/9/embedded/result/

```
$('#filter li a').click(function () {
         $('#filter li.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
         var selector = $(this).parent().attr('data-filter');
         $container.isotope({
             filter: selector,
             animationOptions: {
                 duration: 750,
                 easing: 'linea',
                 queue: false
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
```

---

Just add in CSS

```
#portfolio{
    position: relative;
}
```

And in the jQuery

```
$(".portfolio ul li a").click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
     }, 400);
 });
```

Comment: Hi, that worked perect. Any idea why when i cange the isotope navigation to <!--begin portfolio filter -->
        <ul class="filter" id="filter">
          <li data-filter="*" class="selected"><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li data-filter=".branding"><a href="#">branding</a></li>
          <li data-filter=".design"><a href="#">design</a></li>
          <li data-filter=".development"><a href="#">development</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--end portfolio filter -->  it wont work?

Comment: Well you have changed the classes that you were assigning the filter to work with. Check the updated answer :) And you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it because parseInt cannot be in a string

```
$(".portfolio ul li a").click(function() {
 $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: parseInt($("#top").offset().top)
 }, 400);
});
```

also, on every click function, you could

```
return false;
```

Comment: You don't need parseInt. Just use it like this scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top